# Meaning of ~するとみる and よくばる in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I don't get what するとみた and よくばって　means in this sentence :

> よくばってかなり時間オーバーをするとみた。

As for the context : the speaker is waiting for someone to get out of a room. He just said :

> まる1日ちょうどで出て来るとは限らんぞ。

Rikaichan tells me that 欲張る means "to covet, to lust for" but that doesn't help much...

And I wasn't able to find any information on するとみる.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

見る can mean "to judge or expect through observation" (good dictionaries have that definition).
So, that's "I expect he gets greedy and far exceeds the time limit".

Comment: Oh i see, so, does 見る always have this meaning when used with と and when it has this meaning, is it always used with と?

Comment: Yes and no. ～と見る always means to judge or expect, but "to judge or expect" with 見る is not always expressed in that form. 水が足りなくなることを見て is "expecting we run out of water".